# spring boot for unit test only

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot

i have an application that use classic spring configuration with xml, it is possible to use spring boot for only unit test ?

like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:security-context.xml", 
"classpath:persistence-context-test.xml", "classpath:core-context.xml", 
"classpath:web-context.xml" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SampleTomcatApplicationTests {

@Test
public void testHome() {

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok its easy just create a class with spring boot main method like this:

```
        @SpringBootApplication
        @ImportResource(locations = { "classpath:security-context.xml", "classpath:persistence-context-test.xml", "classpath:core-context.xml", "classpath:web-context.xml" })
        public class SimpleBootCxfSystemTestApplication {

            /**
             * The main method.
             *
             * @param args
             *            the arguments
             */
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                SpringApplication.run(SimpleBootCxfSystemTestApplication.class, args);
            }
        }
```

and change the class test like this:

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = SimpleBootCxfSystemTestApplication.class)
    @WebIntegrationTest("server.port:8080")
    @ActiveProfiles("test")
    @WithUserDetails(value = "testUser", userDetailsServiceBeanName = "utilisateurService")
    public class SampleTomcatApplicationTests {

    //autowired
    ...
    //test
    }
```